# how can i collect the dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to use QScored publica dataset, i download the dump file and used postgresql and pg4admin to restore the dataset. the information is very big and i want to make a single table from 2 or 3 tables but i have this error when i join the two tables that the column name is not defined .

The Sql query

```
select * from class_metric 
join method_metric on class_metric.Project_id = method_metric.Project_id
```

the error

> ERROR:  column class_metric.project_id does not exist
> LINE 2: join method_metric on class_metric.Project_id = method_metri...
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "class_metric.Project_id".
> SQL state: 42703
> Character: 51

how can i solve this error

Comment: try the hint, please

Comment: Seems to me the SQL already does what the HINT suggests. Add tag for RDBMS used.